# AES encrypt string appear \r\n

Tags: ios, objective-c, aes

When I use AES128 encrypt string, if the encrypted string is too long then it will contain \r\n in it. like this [image]

Now I have to use empty string to replace it. Why does the encrypt-string contain the \r\n and any better way to avoid it or fix it.
Thanks.

Answers: it's caused by the Base64 encoding process, every 64 characters will insert a \r\n .

Comment: Please provide the code you are using.

Comment: Nobody knows how you create your encrypted string except you and some psychics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a Base64 encoded string.

Actual encryption output is an array of 8-bit bytes, not characters. The code is Base64 encoding the encrypted data with an option to insert line breaks every 64 characters, this is sometimes to allow better printing of the output. When it is decoded use the `NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters` option to remove line breaks .

In particular for Objective-C the to create a Base64 string from `NSData` is:

```
- (NSString *)base64EncodedStringWithOptions:(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions)options
```

The `options` include:

`NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength`
Set the maximum line length to 64 characters, after which a line ending is inserted.

Which inserts  "\r\n" (carriage return, new line) characters each 64 characters.

If that is not what you want pass 0 as the option value.

To decode Base64 use the Objective-C method:

```
- (instancetype)initWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)base64String options:(NSDataBase64DecodingOptions)options
```

With the option: `NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters`.

Apple code:

> The default implementation of this method will reject non-alphabet characters, including line break characters. To support different encodings and ignore non-alphabet characters, specify an options value of NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters.

The thing that gives it away as a Base64 string is a length that is a multiple of 4, the characters used "a-zA-Z0-9+/" and the trailing "=" characters.

Historic note: These days on OSX and iOS line breaks are a single "\n" (0x0a) line feed character. Back when we used teletypes as terminals "\r" (0x0d) carriage return moved the carriage or print head back but did not move the paper up to the next line. "\n" newline moved the paper up one line but did move the carriage or print head back. They were two distinct mechanical operations. Later some systems used either "\r\n", "\n\r", "\r" or "\n". Unix choose "\n" and thus OSX and iOS.

Comment: Yes it's caused by the Base64 encoding. Thank you.